# Use NumPy to index one array with another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given some data

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.array(['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'])
```

And a sorted index

```
In [3]: i = np.array(['a', 'b'])
```

I want to find the location of each data entry within the index

```
In [4]: # solution here
array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

This is a bit like categoricals.  I don't want to use Pandas here.  I want to do this on fixed length strings.  I need this to be somewhat efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
>>> np.searchsorted(i, x)
array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

The function finds out the index at which each element of `x` should be placed in `i` in order to maintain sorted order.